# Filtering paste in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, filtering, copy-paste

I have `TextBox` which allow insert only numeric values (filtering), But when I paste copied text it's allow any kind of symbol. How can I prevent or filter text before pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could backup your text before any manual input and then when the input provided isn't valid restore the previous text like so:

```
        _backupText = string.Empty;
        doNotPasteTextBox.TextInputStart += (sender, e) =>
                                                {
                                                    int textParsed;
                                                    if(int.TryParse(e.Text,out textParsed))
                                                    {
                                                        _backupText = doNotPasteTextBox.Text.Insert(doNotPasteTextBox.SelectionStart, e.Text);
                                                    }else
                                                    {
                                                        e.Handled = true;
                                                    }
                                                };

        doNotPasteTextBox.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
                                             {
                                                 int textParsed;
                                                 int selectionStart = doNotPasteTextBox.SelectionStart;
                                                 if(!int.TryParse(doNotPasteTextBox.Text, out textParsed))
                                                 {
                                                     doNotPasteTextBox.Text = _backupText;
                                                 }
                                                 doNotPasteTextBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
                                             };
```

I wouldn't recommend [trying to capture the control keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021756/filtering-paste-in-silverlight-4) or anything because when you're on a mac or on linux then you're screwed.

Adjust my sample and pour it inside a new textbox control to make it cleaner but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Clipboard.GetText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597033%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to get the text that is inserted into the textbox, but this will pop up a message, and the user must give the application access to the Clipboard.

If its no problem for you then i would use this.